# Lightning Web Component - How to create a component that wraps another component (transclusion)?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I see that some LWCs can wrap other components, e.g.

```
<lightning-layout>
    <lightning-layout-item>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

I remember for AngularJS, you needed to set transclusion to true for a directive in order to achieve this, but I can't find anything in the LWC docs.

I have tried simply entering content in to my custom LWC, like so:

```
<c-my-modal>
    <p>Some content</p>
</c-my-modal>
```

but none of the content is rendered.

Is there a way this transclusion can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots) is how you do it in LWC. You can pass components into another components using `<slot>` tag.

### Unnamed Slots

This example has an unnamed slot. An unnamed slot is a placeholder for any markup that a parent component passes into the body of c-slot-demo.

```
<!-- slotDemo.html -->
<template>
    <h1>Add content to slot</h1>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here’s the markup for a parent component that uses c-slot-demo.

```
<!-- slotWrapper.html -->
<template>
    <c-slot-demo>
        <p>content from parent</p>
    </c-slot-demo>
</template>
```

When c-slot-demo is rendered, the unnamed slot is replaced with the markup passed into the body of c-slot-demo. Here’s the rendered output of c-slot-wrapper.

```
<h1>Add content to slot</h1>
<div>
    <slot>
        <p>content from parent</p>
    </slot>
</div>
```

If a component has more than one unnamed slot, the markup passed into the body of the component is inserted into all the unnamed slots. This UI pattern is unusual. A component usually has zero or one unnamed slot.

### Named Slots

This example component has two named slots and one unnamed slot.

```
<!-- namedSlots.html -->
<template>
    <p>First Name: <slot name="firstName">Default first name</slot></p>
    <p>Last Name: <slot name="lastName">Default last name</slot></p>
    <p>Description: <slot>Default description</slot></p>
</template>
```

Here’s the markup for a parent component that uses c-named-slots.

```
<!-- slotsWrapper.html -->
<template>
    <c-named-slots>
        <span slot="firstName">Willy</span>
        <span slot="lastName">Wonka</span>
        <span>Chocolatier</span>
    </c-named-slots>
</template>
```

The c-slots-wrapper component passes:

- Willy into the firstName slot
- Wonka into the lastName slot
- Chocolatier into the unnamed slot

Here’s the rendered output.

```
<c-named-slots>
    <p>
        First Name:
        <slot name="firstName"><span slot="firstName">Willy</span></slot>
    </p>
    <p>
        Last Name:
        <slot name="lastName"><span slot="lastName">Wonka</span></slot>
    </p>
    <p>
        Description:
        <slot><span>Chocolatier</span></slot>
    </p>
</c-named-slots>
```

Comment: Please don't use just a link. A few lines of code would substantially improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you for your input. As requested, I copied documentation into my post. Duplicating internet content FTW.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually not exclusive to LWC. Its the standard of [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components). You need to use slots to achieve that. However there are limitations to slots in LWC.

You can create `c-my-modal` as below:

```
<template>
    <h1>Add content to slot</h1>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Also for passing multiple contents, you can use `named slots`.

More information can be found here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots